# Model accuracy starts low and improves after each epoch leading to a high epoch number. Is it bad to have a high epoch number?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I've a model that starts with a very low accuracy but after each epoch it improves a little bit. I get an accuracy of around 0.9 after 45 epochs, which takes quite sometime.

My data set is 3430 images(48x48 pixels) from different kind of flowers (5 types in total and around 650 photos of each type), and my model looks something like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(48, 48, 3)),
keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=45)
```

Is there a way to improve initial accuracy, like adding more layers, changing the type of keras model or adding more images to the dataset. And also is it bad to have a high number of epochs eventhough the model accuracy keeps improving. (Sorry if I have any typos, english is not my main language)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you expect the model to have basically no predictive power when training starts and the weights are random, and to get better with each epoch as the weights converge towards an optimal value. It should eventually converge to some particular loss value which can be thought of as the predictive limit of the architecture.

Initial accuracy with randomly initialized weights will always be arbitrary, which is not a problem.